# Python Convert text to mp3

Tags: python, gtts

Hi I am scraping data from a website and converting text to mp3 but every time it give me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/awais/Desktop/sipgateio-incomingcall-python-master/incoming_call/__main__.py", line 93, in handle_on_dtmf
    ttmp3.save("bbc.mp3")
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 295, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "/home/awais/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 272, in write_to_fp
    raise gTTSError(tts=self)
gTTSError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: Host 'https://translate.google.en/' is not reachable
```

This is what my code look like :

```
URL = requests.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser')


    headlines = soup.select(".gs-c-promo-heading__title")
    all = ""
    for h in headlines:
        h=h.text
        h = h.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        all = str(all) + "  " + str(h)
    print(all)
    ttmp3 = gTTS(all, "en")
    ttmp3.save("bbc.mp3")
```

I am stuck here for last 1 day , please help me

Comment: Try reaching https://translate.google.en/ : it's offline. Maybe the library you use (`gTSS`) has an update, or should request https://translate.google.com/ instead.

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: indeed `gTTSError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: Host 'https://translate.google.en/' is not reachable`

Comment: You don't show the code you use to initialize `gTTS`, but there seems to be a host parameter `tld` there as seen here https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#gtts.tts.gTTS

Comment: Maybe try `gTTS = gtts.tts.gTTS(tld="translate.google.com")`

Comment: have you tried to use [polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) from amazon?

Comment: this is how I am initializing just importing it  from gtts import gTTS

Comment: okay give me a minute

Comment: strange thing is same code is working on windows but on Linux it is not

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much guys , I resolved it by changing this parameter :

```
ttmp3 = gTTS(text=all,lang="en",tld="com")
```

By putting tld="com" we can fix it